# Jmeter groovy classes not unloading

Tags: class, groovy, memory-leaks, jmeter

I am running Jmeter tests using JMeter 5.4.1 and Groovy and openjdk version "16".

During these test l see the heap memory progressively increases up to the point to provoke an Out of Memory exception - metaspace and a heap dump.

I have increased the metaspace memory allocation but there is need to go to higher volumes which current memory allocation will not support.

From Jconsole I can see that Loaded Classes continuously increase, up to the point of 100K+ classes loaded.

I've run JMeter using -verbose:classes, and there are thousand of lines regarding loading "Script" classes like:

[Loaded Script1 from file: /groovy/script]

[Loaded Script2 from file: /groovy/script]

[Loaded Script3 from file: /groovy/script]

[...]

[Loaded Script2409 from file: /groovy/script]

All my JSR223 groovy scripts are check to cache complied scripts.

I plan to combination different version of JDK and Jmeter hoping that will help and removing jmeter parameter from Groovy script hoping that will help but not sure.

Can you recommend a solution ?

Comment: "Can you recommend a solution ?"- Is the solution you are asking for one that would lessen the number of classes being loaded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing JSR223 script using variable as suggested in [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#developing_scripts)

> it can be stored as a variable on the Test Plan. The script variable can then be used to create the function call. For example, suppose a Groovy script is stored in the variable RANDOM_NAME. The function call can then be coded as `${__groovy(${RANDOM_NAME})}`

Answer (score 0):

The only straightforward solution would be [compiling your Groovy scripts into .jar files](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time/) and call them from [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.html) samplers.

Alternatively you can consider [developing your own JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)